# Can't figure out how to make a combat system on Lua in Roblox Studio

Tags: lua, roblox

I am a new programmer and have been working with some of my friends on Roblox. We have been trying to make a game with a fun combat system, but have failed in every attempt, although we're not ready to give up.

We've tried googling things, searching tutorials on YouTube and have been trying for about a week to get this to work. We can barely get a punch animation to play when our goal is to make a combat system with a normal attack that combos up to 5, a skill that can be used every 15 seconds, and an ultimate ability that charges whenever you hit an enemy.
Thank you to anyone that can help, I feel as if I'm in way over my head and I don't really know where to start.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! I'm sorry, but such vague, open questions or questions along the lines of "please implement this for us" aren't fit for StackOverflow - take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) or visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) to see which questions are suitable for StackOverflow. What exactly have you tried, where have you failed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code if u can read it :P

```js
--Server Script

local re=Instance.new("RemoteEvent",game.ReplicatedStorage)
-- all abilities(except the ultimate)are not on cooldown at start of the game
local ability_cds={
    ["basicAttack"]=1,
    ["r"]=15, -- Skill1 (binded to button r with 15s cooldown)
    ["t"]=60 -- Ultimate ability
}
local ultcd=60 -- ultimate ability default cooldown
local function ultcd_update(player,cd) 
    re:FireClient(player,"t",5) 
end
local ability={
    ["basicAttack"]=function(player,combo)
        local hint=workspace:FindFirstChild"Message"or Instance.new("Hint",workspace)
        hint.Text="basicAttack x"..combo
    end,
    ["r"]=function(player,combo) -- Skill1 (binded to button r with 15s cooldown)
    end,
    ["t"]=function(player) --[[Ultimate ability(charging cd by kill not implemented)
        
ultcd_update(player,5) -- use to decrease ultimate cooldown by 5seconds(example)

]]  
    end
    
    
}
local maxcombo=5
local function useAbility(ability_name,player,combo)
    ability[ability_name](player,combo)
end
local ability_combo,ability_cds2={},{}
re.OnServerEvent:Connect(function(player,ability)
    if not ability or type(ability)~="string"then player:Kick()end
    local cd=ability_cds[ability]
    if not cd then player:Kick()end
    ability_cds2[player.Name]=ability_cds2[player.Name]or table.clone(ability_cds)
    local ability_cds=ability_cds2[player.Name]
    cd=ability_cds[ability]
    -- ultimate charging mechanism override:
    --(ult. cooldown will not decrease every second)
    if ability=="t"and cd==0 then
        ability_cds[ability]=ultcd
        useAbility("t",player,0)
    end
    --
    if cd==0 then return end
    ability_cds[ability]=0
    ability_combo[player.Name]=ability_combo[player.Name]or {}
    ability_combo[player.Name][ability]=ability_combo[player.Name][ability]or 0
    if not(ability_combo[player.Name][ability]+1>maxcombo) then
        ability_combo[player.Name][ability]+=1
        else
        ability_combo[player.Name][ability]=1
        end
    delay(cd,function()
        ability_cds[ability]=cd
        local combo=ability_combo[player.Name][ability]
        delay(cd,function()
            if combo==ability_combo[player.Name][ability]then
                ability_combo[player.Name][ability]=0
            end
            
        end)
    end)
    spawn(function()
        useAbility(ability,player,ability_combo[player.Name][ability])
    end)
end)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
```

```js
--LocalScript



local player=game.Players.LocalPlayer

--local gui=script.Parent

local char=player.Character
local hum=char:WaitForChild"Humanoid"

local mouse=player:GetMouse()
local re=game.ReplicatedStorage:WaitForChild"RemoteEvent"
local ability_cds={
    ["basicAttack"]=1,
    ["r"]=15, -- Skill1 (binded to button r with 15s cooldown)
    ["t"]=60 -- Ultimate ability
}
re.OnClientEvent:Connect(function(ability,cd)
    local newcd=ability_cds[ability]-cd
    newcd=newcd<0 and 0 or newcd
    ability_cds[ability]=cd
end)
local ultcd=60
local function useAbility(ability)
    local cd=ability_cds[ability]
    -- ultimate ability special charging mechanism
    if ability=="t"then
        if cd==0 then
            ability_cds[ability]=ultcd
            re:FireServer(ability)
        end
        return
    end
    --
    if not cd or cd==0 then return end
    ability_cds[ability]=0
    delay(cd,function()
        ability_cds[ability]=cd
    end)
    re:FireServer(ability)
end
mouse.KeyDown:Connect(function(key)
    useAbility(key:lower())
end)
mouse.Button1Down:Connect(function(key)
    useAbility("basicAttack")
end)
```